# C# how to make function for all buttons using object sender

Tags: c#, function, object

I´m using WindowsForm and working with flat design. In the program there are 6 buttons, these buttons are made of a label and a panel. The label controls all the actions that the button can do. when i started writing the program i made one function for each button, now i like to use one function that controls all buttons. I have tried to make that work but I´m stuck and can´t find a way to solve it.

Been looking around at the forum for solutions but i think that i might not know what i´m looking for.

This is what i made so far.

```
Buttons[] cobra = new Buttons[5];

    private class Buttons
    {
        private bool position;
        private string name;

        public bool Position
        {
            get { return position; }
            set { position = value; }
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }


    }

    private void SetButtons()
    {
        cobra[0].Name = "label3";
        cobra[0].Position = false;
        cobra[1].Name = "label4";
        cobra[1].Position = false;
    }

    private void CheckStatusButtons(object import)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < cobra.Length; i++)
        {

        }
    }

    private class ToggelFunction
    {
        private bool hawk;
        public bool Hawk
        {
            get { return hawk; }
            set { hawk = value; }
        }
    }

    ToggelFunction tiger = new ToggelFunction();

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (tiger.Hawk == false)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.PaleGreen;
            label3.Text = "ON";
            if (myport.IsOpen)
            {
                send(new byte[] { 16, 128, 32, 16, 1 });
            }
            tiger.Hawk = true;
            return;
        }

        if (tiger.Hawk == true)
        {
            button1.BackColor = Color.DarkSeaGreen;
            label3.Text = "2";
            if (myport.IsOpen)
            {
                send(new byte[] { 16, 128, 32, 8, 1 });
            }
            tiger.Hawk = false;
            return;
        }
    }
```

**"label3_Click"** this is my function for button 1, all buttons look the same just different variables.

As I found on the forum, you can use object sender to i identify which button that made the click and from there use that in the function to make action.
So all buttons will use this functions, i´m not sure how to compare values in the if statement, if button 1 is click then it should check what values button 1 has.

My idea was to make a **class "Buttons"** and an array to store all the values of each button, it´s not completed yet. When a button is clicked it checks 
with the array what values that button has and compare that in the function depending on what the action is. The first action would be to check if the button is on or off. If it´s off then it enters that if statement and there some actions will happen, change of color and the text, these values also have to be stored in the array i guess.

I have tried to compare the array with object sender, but i get some error saying that you can´t compare bool with object i think.

So i wonder if some one might have a solution or suggestions?

Comment: `Button button = (Button)sender;`

Comment: The button variable is passed to the event handler as `sender`. Just cast it to Button as @itsme86 suggested. Then you have your button right there in the method and you can do whatever you need to with it. Good effort to try to resolve it yourself, but there's an easier solution =)

Comment: @itsme86, i will try that and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad, i´m interested in that easier solution?

Comment: @Nivmer I added my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a simple example of what i think you want to do. bare in mind this does not abide by all coding best practises but its not a mess either. You will need to put your safety null checks in.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public class ButtonVariables
    {
        public int value1 { get; set; }
        public int value2 { get; set; }
    }

    Dictionary<string, ButtonVariables> bv = new Dictionary<string, ButtonVariables>();

    private void ProcessClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonVariables vars = GetVariables(sender);
        //Do stuff with your variable set here
    }
    private ButtonVariables GetVariables(object sender)
    {
        ButtonVariables returnValue = new ButtonVariables();
        switch (((Button)sender).Name.ToLower())
        {
            case "buttona":
                return bv["A"];
            case "buttonb":
                return bv["B"];
            case "buttonc":
                return bv["C"];
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
    private void ButtonA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessClick(sender, e);
    }

    private void ButtonB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessClick(sender, e);
    }

    private void ButtonC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProcessClick(sender, e);
    }
  }
```

I've basically added two methods to handle your method. One to identify the button and get its related values from a dictionary that you will have to populate with your `Buttons` class. and one to carry out the logic.

**EDIT**

As requested in the comments here's an easy (but not the only way) to point your event listeners towards the same method.

Initially you need to set up with one button and double click it or do some other way to create the forms `Button_Click()` Event Method. At this point an event listener delegate has been added to your `Form.Designer.cs` File. Open that file and you will see something like this:

```
// 
// ButtonA
// 
this.ButtonA.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
this.ButtonA.Name = "ButtonA";
this.ButtonA.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
this.ButtonA.TabIndex = 0;
this.ButtonA.Text = "button1";
this.ButtonA.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.ButtonA.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonA_Click);
```

What you need to do is create your other buttons and add this code in for them with a change to the last line `new System.EventHandler(this.ButtonA_Click);` This line basically states which method to call when the ButtonA.Click event is invoked. At this point you can add what ever method you want (as long as you name is nicely for good convention). So your example would be this :

```
// 
// ButtonA
// 
this.ButtonA.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
this.ButtonA.Name = "ButtonA";
this.ButtonA.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
this.ButtonA.TabIndex = 0;
this.ButtonA.Text = "button1";
this.ButtonA.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.ButtonA.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ProcessClick);
// 
// ButtonB
// 
this.ButtonB.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
this.ButtonB.Name = "ButtonB";
this.ButtonB.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
this.ButtonB.TabIndex = 0;
this.ButtonB.Text = "B";
this.ButtonB.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.ButtonB.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ProcessClick);
// 
// ButtonC
// 
this.ButtonC.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
this.ButtonC.Name = "ButtonC";
this.ButtonC.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
this.ButtonC.TabIndex = 0;
this.ButtonC.Text = "C";
this.ButtonC.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
this.ButtonC.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.ProcessClick);
```

Remember you need to physically create the buttons on the form itself.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the button name as the dictionary key to eliminate the need for the `switch`?

Comment: Ah yes that’s a good point however I was not sure about how or where the values are calculated so there is room for refactoring there. You are correct though. Please edit if you can.

Comment: @thanatorr, thank you, very interesting this example, I did not know about dictionary. Do have to make one method for each button as u have done or can i make one method that takes all buttons?

Comment: @Nivmer it is possible yes though if your a beginner id recommend this way first as there isn't really any problem with it. But what you want to do i change your event listeners to point to one method (the event listeners in a winform application are generated in the form design when you create the `Button_Click()`Event Method. I will updater my answer with an easy way to do this.

Comment: @thanatorr, i have been testing your code and thank you for writing it, It´s allot to take in but i will get there. I just wonder about itsme86 comment to eliminate the "switch"? If the Switch is removed what do you do with that method, just leave it as it is or do you put something else there?

Comment: @Nivmer the method and switch is an example of how you might retrieve your data and do extra work with it before using it. If the Switch is removed, you don't really need that method. You can simply get youir (pre-poulated) dictionary value in the main `ProcessClick` method like this, `ButtonVariables vars = bv[((Button)sender).Name]` You must chose to have the button names as your dictionary keys and cast the `sender` as a button to access the name property.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have three labels and a panel for each label. You can add the event handler to all of them and whenever that event fires the event handler will use that label as the `sender`. To keep the panel associated with the label, you could add the panel to the label's tag property. Then, in the event handler you can then get the panel from the label.

```
label1.Click += label_Click;
label2.Click += label_Click;
label3.Click += label_Click;
label1.Tag = panel1;
label2.Tag = panel2;
label3.Tag = panel3;
```

In the event handler, just cast `sender` to Label and there you have your label object to do whatever you want with and like I said, the panel is in the Tag property. I did a little refactoring to your code to make it cleaner looking.

```
private void label_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this is what itsme86 was suggesting in the comments
    var label = (Label)sender;
    var panel = (Panel)label.Tag;

    label.BackColor = tiger.Hawk ? Color.DarkSeaGreen : Color.PaleGreen;
    label.Text = tiger.Hawk ? "2" : "ON";
    if (myport.IsOpen)
        send(new byte[] { 16, 128, 32, 8, 1 });
    tiger.Hawk = !tiger.Hawk;
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions about this.

Comment: Yeah it works like how i was thinking but there is one problem maybe i have missed something. After the first click then every click after the

Comment: method is repeating it self.  I change the IF statement to a MessagBox.Show to see that it works. But after the first click it goes through the method twice and after that it 3 time and so on, it´s like a For Loop that increases every click.  Hope you under stand my explanation

Comment: @Nivmer Where did you add `button1.Click += button_Click;` in your code? It could be that you're adding a new event handler to click every time it is clicked.

Comment: first i didn´t know exactly where to put button1.Click += button_Click; so yeah i put in a .Click method. After reading your comment I put it in Form 1 and now it works fine.

Comment: I see that there has been a miss understanding, i should have thought about this earlier.  My buttons in my program are not real buttons, as i explained in my text the are made of a Label and a panel. when i now try to add the code to my program i get some problems with labels as they don´t function like buttons.

Comment: @Nivmer The same concept should apply though (except for adding the label to the Tag property) Just do `label1.Click += button_Click;` except rename that to `label_Click` and change the sender to be cast as a Label.

Comment: I got the the label to work fine and the button turn on and off thank you for that, it´s just the the action that happen in the method that i have some difficulties with. I have been trying to get the panel that is associated with the label to change color, i´m not sure how to cast it or something like that. As i understand the panel is not sent in to the method so then it can´t identify.

Comment: @Nivmer You could do `label1.Tag = panel1;` and then in the label_Click method you could get the panel with `var label = (Label)sender; var panel = (Panel)label.Tag;`

Comment: @Nivmer I have updated my answer to use Label and Panel instead of Button.