# It's possible to define function to imported buttons

Tags: c#

So i found this answer my question [How i create user panel using multiple panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71883697/how-i-create-user-panel-using-multiple-panel) but instead of panels I have buttons, and for each button i want to execute a function when i click on it. It is possible?

(**It looks like what I want but I don't understand the example** [C# how to make function for all buttons using object sender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49495498/c-sharp-how-to-make-function-for-all-buttons-using-object-sender))

Comment: All of a WinForms UI is instantiated by the code in `InitalizeComponent` (in your form's designer file), so it seems rather redundant to ask if it's possible. Take a look at the designer file and you can probably figure out how to write code to build the UI dynamically.

Comment: DiplomacyNotWar my form has nothing else than a switch button and a label. So i don't know how to